# How to validate input property name in Web API C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have below API endpoint which has input member ID and member details. I am testing it from postman but despite passing wrong property name, API is working fine. I am not getting how its working fine.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Emp>>> GetStudentMarks(long rollNo, [FromBody] Subject subs)
{
//do stuff
}
```

My Subject class is

```
public class Subject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Array of subject names
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string[] SubjectNames { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Include Last Semester Marks or not
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public bool? IncludeLastSemesterMarks { get; set; }

   }
```

When I am testing it locally in postman with below URL, its working fine.

> https://localhost:7120/v1/API/getstudentmarks/1234

```
{
  "SubjectNames": ["English", "History"],
  "**LastSemesterMarks**": true
}
```

My property name in request is wrong and stil its working fine. Any idea please, why it is so

Comment: The property is different, not wrong. Since `IncludeLastSemesterMarks` isn't required, it doesn't have to appear in JSON. `"**LastSemesterMarks**"` is an extra property. The JSON string provided an extra property and didn't provide an optional one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core - System.Text.Json: how to reject unknown properties in payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74995241/asp-net-core-system-text-json-how-to-reject-unknown-properties-in-payload)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos now I have made the property as required and removed its default value as well still facing the same issue.

Comment: The field is having default value which then will not be invalid. Make it field 'IncludeLastSemesterMarks' as nullable (bool?) so it will work. ref link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @LevananGan I changed it to nullable and still does not solved my problem

Comment: Hi @learningdotnet, did you do something special? For example, ignore NullValue and so on. `[Required] public bool? IncludeLastSemesterMarks { get; set; }` should be right, it will give 400 error: `The IncludeLastSemesterMarks field is required.`.

Comment: @Chen I did exactly what you suggest. Its still working fine with incorrect value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this. I added following line in my program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options
        => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = false);
```